# How to modify the prepended protocol and host in Tomcat's RewriteValve

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I am using the RewriteValve in Tomcat 8 to redirect client requests like so:

`RewriteRule /login$ /~autoLogin [R,L]`

This is fine but the problem I'm running into is that when a redirect is used `[R]`, the redirect target URL is created by prepending the server with http:// rather than what the client originally requested (the docs say that this will be the case [[1]](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)).

For example, when the client requests

`https://myserver.com/login` I expect it to redirect to
`https://myserver.com/~autologin`.

However, it actually redirects to `http://myserver.com/~autologin`

How can I configure/change how the prepending works?

At the moment I am working around this by hardcoding the target URL to

`https://myserver.com/~autologin`

but this is undesirable as I keep this configuration in version control and use it on multiple servers for developing, test, staging and production.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is not a problem with the RewriteValve, but a side effect of the server infrastructure I am using.

The Tomcat server is running on an EC2 instance behind an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS. The ELB hosts the certificate that allows HTTPS requests. However, because the EC2 instance can't use the certificate directly, the request that comes in as HTTPS on the ELB gets forwarded to the Tomcat instance as an HTTP request; the ELB will transparently negotiate the certificate exchange and encryption of the communications.

Thus, to the RewriteValve, the incoming request is on HTTP and thus, it prepends with HTTP.